# Refresh viewmodel in app OnResume

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have an Xamarin Forms app that has some pages and related viewmodels behind it. On the pages in OnAppearing it sets the binding context to the view model. The view model calls a web api to retrieve the data.
When the app goes to sleep and is called again I use the OnResume event in the App class and messagecenter to send a message. In the OnAppearing of the page I subscribe to the message and set the binding context to a new viewmodel. In the OnDisapearing I unsubscribe from the message to prevent it from receiving event when the page is not visible (another page is visible).

Is there no way to call a methods from the page it’s connected binding context? Or is it only possible to refresh the information by setting the page it’s binding context again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `BindingContext` in the `OnAppearing` event will reassign the `ViewModel` each time you navigate to or back to your `Page` (depends on the platform). Usually you set the `ViewModel` once and in the constructor.

Regarding the `MessagingCenter`. Before the `OnPause` there will be a `OnDisappearing` event. So, you will unsubscribe from the message and most probably will not receive anymore after `OnResume`.

Beside this, there are platform specific behaviours related to `OnAppearing` and `OnDisappearing`. Luckily the [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical/) is covering the exception cases as well.

I am not sure I fully understand your question, but, you can call a method from a `BindingContext` on the `Page` the next way:

```
public partial class MyPage : Page
{
    public MyPage()
    {
        this.BindingContext = new MyViewModel();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        (this.BindingContext as MyViewModel)?.MyMethod();
    }
}
```